# How to compare sublists of two lists as single entities?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two arrays, each having multiple sublists with 3 items each. I am trying to compare the sublists of both these lists as single entities instead of checking items from sublist of List1 with items from sublist of List2.
These values are pulled from excel sheet using df.vaues

I have tried using conventional python list functions and using nested for loops

```
arr1:  [['AU002' '000000000037080' 'VB_ADJ']  ['AU002' '000000000037080' 'VB_ADJ']  ['AU002' '000000000039325' 'VB_ADJ']  ['AU002' '000000000039325' 'VB_ADJ']]

arr2:  [['AU002' '000000000037080' 'HUNTER_DOUGLAS']  ['AU002' '000000000037080' 'EXP'] ['AU002' '000000000037080' 'GEN']  ['AU002' '000000000037080' 'VB_ADJ']  ['AU002' '000000000039325' 'EXP']]
```

Here the element 4 of arr1 is not present in arr2 but with the approaches I used I couldn't get the right output

```
#1.
mask = np.isin (arr1, arr2)
mask

#2.
i=0
for each in arr1:
   j=0
   if(i<3):
       for every in arr2:
           if(j<3):
               if(each[i]==every[j]):
                   print("found",each[i])
            else :
                print("not found",each[i])
        j+=1
i+=1

#3.
for each in arr1:
    for every in arr2:
        if each==every:
            print('found')
        else:
            print('not found')
#4.
result =  all(elem in arr2  for elem in arr1)
if result:
    print('Found')
else:
    print('Not Found')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numpy's array_equal can work well here. You can read more about it here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html

```
import numpy as np

lis1= [['AU002', '000000000037080', 'VB_ADJ'],  ['AU002', '000000000037080' ,'VB_ADJ'] , ['AU002' ,'000000000039325', 'VB_ADJ'],  ['AU002', '000000000039325', 'VB_ADJ']]
lis2=[['AU002', '000000000037080', 'HUNTER_DOUGLAS'] , ['AU002', '000000000037080', 'EXP'] ,['AU002', '000000000037080' ,'GEN'],  ['AU002' ,'000000000037080' ,'VB_ADJ'] , ['AU002' ,'000000000039325', 'EXP']]

for i in lis1:
    lis=[]
    for j in lis2:
        lis.append(np.array_equal(i,j))
    if True in lis:
        print('Found ', i)
    else:
        print('Not Found ', i)
```

**Output**

```
Found  ['AU002', '000000000037080', 'VB_ADJ']
Found  ['AU002', '000000000037080', 'VB_ADJ']
Not Found  ['AU002', '000000000039325', 'VB_ADJ']
Not Found  ['AU002', '000000000039325', 'VB_ADJ']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
found_list = [elem in arr2 for elem in arr1]
```

**Testing it out:**

```
arr1 = [['AU002', '000000000037080', 'VB_ADJ'],
        ['AU002', '000000000037080', 'VB_ADJ'],
        ['AU002', '000000000039325', 'VB_ADJ'],
        ['AU002', '000000000039325', 'VB_ADJ']]
arr2 = [['AU002', '000000000037080', 'HUNTER_DOUGLAS'],
        ['AU002', '000000000037080', 'EXP'],
        ['AU002', '000000000037080', 'GEN'],
        ['AU002', '000000000037080', 'VB_ADJ'],
        ['AU002', '000000000039325', 'EXP']]

found_list = [elem in arr2 for elem in arr1]
print (found_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[True, True, False, False] # Only 0-th and 1-st elems of arr1 are in arr2
```

Answer (score 0):

If your lists are in following format:

```
a1 = [['AU002' ,'000000000037080' ,'VB_ADJ'],  ['AU002', '000000000037080' ,'VB_ADJ'],  ['AU002', '000000000039325' ,'VB_ADJ'],  ['AU002', '000000000039325' ,'VB_ADJ']]

 b1 = [['AU002' ,'000000000037080' ,'HUNTER_DOUGLAS'] , ['AU002', '000000000037080', 'EXP'] ,['AU002', '000000000037080' ,'GEN'] , ['AU002' ,'000000000037080' ,'VB_ADJ'] , ['AU002', '000000000039325', 'EXP']]
```

Just :

```
[sublist_a1 for sublist_a1 in a1 for sublist_b1 in b1 if sublist_a1 == sublist_b1]
```

Gives the sublist present in both lists:

```
[['AU002', '000000000037080', 'VB_ADJ'],
 ['AU002', '000000000037080', 'VB_ADJ']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here below is the snippet which would help

```
from pandas import DataFrame

arr1 = [['AU002', '000000000037080', 'VB_ADJ'],
        ['AU002', '000000000037080', 'VB_ADJ'],
        ['AU002', '000000000039325', 'VB_ADJ'],
        ['AU002', '000000000039325', 'VB_ADJ']]
arr2 = [['AU002', '000000000037080', 'HUNTER_DOUGLAS'],
        ['AU002', '000000000037080', 'EXP'],
        ['AU002', '000000000037080', 'GEN'],
        ['AU002', '000000000037080', 'VB_ADJ'],
        ['AU002', '000000000039325', 'EXP']]

df1 = DataFrame.from_records(arr1)
df1.columns = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"]

df2 = DataFrame.from_records(arr2)
df2.columns = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"]

df1['compressed']=df1.apply(lambda x:'%s%s%s' % (x['Col1'],x['Col2'],x['Col3']),axis=1)
df2['compressed']=df2.apply(lambda x:'%s%s%s' % (x['Col1'],x['Col2'],x['Col3']),axis=1)
df1['Success'] = df1['compressed'].isin(df2['compressed']).astype(int)

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
    Col1             Col2    Col3                  compressed  Success
0  AU002  000000000037080  VB_ADJ  AU002000000000037080VB_ADJ        1
1  AU002  000000000037080  VB_ADJ  AU002000000000037080VB_ADJ        1
2  AU002  000000000039325  VB_ADJ  AU002000000000039325VB_ADJ        0
3  AU002  000000000039325  VB_ADJ  AU002000000000039325VB_ADJ        0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code:
Worked fine for me. Thank You all for your answers. Best Regards.

Since cmp() function is not available in python 3.x

```
def cmp(a, b):
    if((a>b) - (a<b) ==0):
        return True
    else:
        pass
flag=0
for i in invoice_temp2:
    for j in val_query2:
        if(cmp(i,i)):
            flag=0
            break
        else:
            flag=1
            continue

if flag==1:
    print('Not Found')
else:
    print('Found')
```